# HTML and CSS full image background

Tags: html, css, background-image

It seems that my full image isn't going all the way to the top.

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.nav-bar{
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align:center;
 position:relative;
 font-family:navfont;
}

 .nav-bar > a{
  text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;

}

.nav-bar a:hover{
  color:#FF0000;
}

.backgroundimg{
  background: url("../img/background.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

[image: My image]

Comment: Where's your markup? We need to see your HTML, too, so we have a [mcve] to work with. It would help if you could host and include your background image in the example, too.

Comment: The CSS is great to include, but your HTML structure would be helpful as well.

Comment: From the image that I see, what you can do is actually add the background image to the BODY. Right NOW you have two DIVs.

Comment: OR, add a `z-index` to your `nav` and place the position to the top. If you don't want to make the whole page have that background.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should add the `backgroundimg` class to your `<body>` tag, because I'm pretty sure that you HTML markup is something like this :

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            ...
        </nav>
        <div class="backgroundimg">
            ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And should be more like this :

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body class="backgroundimg">
        <nav>
            ...
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```